# Nested ajax call with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to replace 'button one' with 'button two' then 'button two' with 'button three' then 'button three' with 'button ok' with nested ajax call using jquery. But after replacing button one with button two it doesn't work. Where am I wrong? Please help.

```
<!--This is my html code.......-->
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <button id="one">button one</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#one").click(function(){
                $.post("show.php",
                {
                    id: "two"
                },
                function(data,status){
                    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = data;
                });
            });
            $("#two").click(function(){
                $.post("show.php",
                {
                    id: "three"
                },
                function(data,status){
                    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = data;
                });
            });
            $("#three").click(function(){
                $.post("show.php",
                {
                    id: "ok"
                },
                function(data,status){
                    document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = data;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is show.php page code

```
<?php
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
echo"
    <button id='$id'>button $id</button>
";
?>
```

Comment: Technically your Ajax calls are not *nested*. Just called separately. What is the overall aim?

Comment: You need to add the on clicks after you add the button.  Or do an `$('body').on('click', '#two', function(){})`

Comment: why is it not working. Am I doing something wrong @GoneCoding

Comment: You should take a look at the DOM after your first click: You are nesting `button` elements instead of replacing them. And to bind events to elements that don't exist yet on page load, you need event delegation.

Comment: I am building a website. When I click filter it shows the products as well as pagination (filter and pagination both working on ajax). but when I click on any pagination it doesn't work. So I am testing with this codes which is also not working.... Any suggestion @GoneCoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is right, but once you replace the previous html from the new one dynamically, the click even registered on the start is useless. You should use event delegation in this case. Please read this.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

And use this as the click event::

```
$( "parent_element" ).on( "click", "updated_child_element", function( event ) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: That's *part* of the problem, yes, but not the whole thing.

Comment: Problem is solved replacing `$(document).on("click", "#one", function() {  //code }`  with your code. @Hemant Manwani... thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. Setting the `innerHTML` on a button changes the *content* of the button, it doesn't replace the button. You can't have a button inside another button; the [content model for `button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) (what it's allowed to have inside it) is *"[Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), but there must be no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant"* and of course, `button`s are interactive content. You want `$("#originalbutton").replaceWith(newContent);`
2. Your event handlers for the subsequent buttons never get hooked up, because you're trying to hook them up before they exist. Look at using *event delegation* instead.

See comments:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Note event delegation
  $(document).on("click", "#one", function() {
    // timeout to simulate ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#one").replaceWith('<button id="two">Button Two</button>');
    }, 100);
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#two", function() {
    // timeout to simulate ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#two").replaceWith('<button id="three">Button Three</button>');
    }, 100);
  });
  $(document).on("click", "#three", function() {
    // timeout to simulate ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#three").replaceWith('<button id="ok">Button OK</button>');
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="one">Button One</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Harshanil Mark the answer as accepted to indicate it solved your problem/